# Why is my python program printing a statement twice at the end?

Tags: python, function, if-statement

So I'm finished with the program as far as I can tell but I have a formatting type issue where the last print statement in the `def main()` function is printing twice and I can't figure out why - very annoying. Anyway I'm sure it's something simple that I'm missing, here's my code:

```
import math

#----------------------------------------------------
# distance(draw,angle)
#
# This function computes the distance of the shot
#----------------------------------------------------

def distance(draw,angle):
    velocity = draw*10
    x = (angle)
    sin_deg = math.sin(math.radians(2*x))
    g = 32.2
    dist = (((velocity**2) * sin_deg) / g)
    return dist

#----------------------------------------------------
# Main Program #
#----------------------------------------------------

dist_to_pig = int(input("Distance to pig (feet) -------- "))

def main():
    angle_of_elev = float(input("Angle of elevation (degrees) -- "))
    draw_length = float(input("Draw length (inches) ---------- "))
    print()
    distance_calc = round(distance(draw_length,angle_of_elev))
    short_result = int(round(dist_to_pig - distance_calc))
    long_result = int(round(distance_calc - dist_to_pig))


    if distance_calc < (dist_to_pig - 2):
        print("Result of shot ---------------- ", (short_result - 2), "feet too short")
        print()
        main()
    if distance_calc > (dist_to_pig + 2):
        print("Result of shot ---------------- ", (long_result - 2), "feet too long")
        print()
        main()
    else:
        print("OINK!")

#----------------------------------------------------
# Execution #
#----------------------------------------------------

main()
```

If you see any other problems in my code feel free to point that out. thanks!

Comment: You are calling the main function recursively at line number 39 , is it intentional??

Comment: Which line exactly is printing twice? Try to change the 2nd if statement to elif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JediObiJohn, OINK is printing multiple times because of recursion. Change the second if to **elif** and it should fix your problem.

Comment: This fixed it! That's what i get for trying to use recursion lol. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main(i):
    if i < 2:
        print(i)
    if i > 2:
        print(i)
    else:
        print("Hello")
```

Based on this simple program, if you try a few cases:

```
>>> main(1)
>>> 1
Hello
>>> main(3)
3
>>> main(2)
Hello
```

Did you see the difference? When the first `IF` is `TRUE`, then the 2nd 
`IF` will be `FALSE` and hence the `ELSE` part will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you actual want is:

```
if distance_calc < (dist_to_pig - 2):
    main()
elif distance_calc > (dist_to_pig - 2):
    main()
else:
    print("OK")
```

am I right? 
if you use 2 'if's, then when `distance_calc < (dist_to_pig -2)` happens, 2 lines of code executed. `main()` and `print(...)`. that's why you can see muliple times of 'OK' printed.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling main() function twice, once to start execution and once inside your function